# how to copy the contents of sd card to another

Tags: sd-card, beagleboard

I have sd card, I installed ubuntu on it in order to use it in beagleboard.

Is there a program to copy the entire contents of the sd card to another one??!!

I basically want to copy the operating system to the other sd card.

Comment: There's a related post here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5440/copy-existing-raspbian-installation-to-smaller-sd-card

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concerned, you need to "install" it again on another SD card. You can copy certain files but the Os just cannot be "copied" like that. The solution is to take the -iso image of the OS and reinstall it to another SD.

---

EDITED:

I've been looking deeper and maybe the Win32DiskImager program that is normally used to install image files to SD cards, could also "clone" your SD card. Try to download it, and as soon as you open it you have a "read" option, that would provide you a solution.Cloning the SD card is simple. Just follow these steps:P

> Extracted from: http://lifehacker.com/how-to-clone-your-raspberry-pi-sd-card-for-super-easy-r-1261113524
>
> Follow these steps to clone the SD card:
>
> - Get everything set up just the way you want it on your Raspberry Pi, whatever you're using it for. Then shut down the Pi and remove the
>   SD card. Insert the SD card into your computer.
> - Start up Win32DiskImager, a program that you probably have from when you first set up your Pi. (If you're on OS X or Linux, you'll
>   have to use the dd command as described here instead of these steps).
> - In the "Image File" box, enter the path of your soon-to-be image file. For example, I put mine in C:\Users\Whitson\images\myraspbmc.img
> - Under the "Device" box, select your SD card.
> - Click the "Read" button to create the image file from your card.
> - When it's done creating the image file, you can eject your SD card and put it back in your Raspberry Pi. Keep that IMG file in a safe
>   place.